# In Rails, can't add new methods to Array::Class in development env (works in test env)

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

In my Rails app, in *app/models/*, I have a file named **array.rb** which contains the following code :

```
class Array
  def sum_f
    #my code
  end
end
```

When I run the console, **Array.new.respond_to?(:sum_f)** returns **false** whereas the *test console* returns **true** (and the method works nicely).

I've figured out that setting **config.cache_classes** to **true** in *development.rb* fixes this but my guess is that it is not the correct solution.

Any ideas why my modifications to the Array class are being ignored in the development ENV ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails, in development, lazily loads files. Which means unless you explicitely require it, the file isn't loaded until you require it's class.

What I do is that I create an initializer, like `config/initializers/core_ext.rb`
Which includes all my application's core extensions.

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'core_ext', '**', '*.rb)].each {|f| require f}
```

Then, add all your core extensions in the `lib/core_ext` (like `lib/core_ext/array` for your example) directory and they'll be automatically loaded when you start the application.
This also means that every time you change a core extension file, you need to restart your rails server.